# How to get favicon's URL from a generic webpage in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I need a way to get the favicon's URL from a generic webpage considering that the favicon is not always at the base url.

P.s. without using an external service or library.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon#Accessibility already provides so many clues.

Comment: @xRobot: If you want people to just write the code for you, there are several sites out there for doing that. StackOverflow is not the place.

Comment: the question is closed. I don't find it ambiguous, etc.
anyway, maybe this'll help:
https://gist.github.com/davidmaxwaterman/aa0368be171249ebe14e59e75468e04b

Answer (score 37, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
var getFavicon = function(){
    var favicon = undefined;
    var nodeList = document.getElementsByTagName("link");
    for (var i = 0; i < nodeList.length; i++)
    {
        if((nodeList[i].getAttribute("rel") == "icon")||(nodeList[i].getAttribute("rel") == "shortcut icon"))
        {
            favicon = nodeList[i].getAttribute("href");
        }
    }
    return favicon;        
}

alert(getFavicon());​
```

Or have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/PBpgY/3/ for an online example.

Comment: Thank you, Is there a way to get the full URL and not only /favicon.png ?

Comment: If you try this on stackoverflow.com for example, it wouldn't work, because of the `rel="shortcut icon"` attribute they used. Have a look at mine.

Comment: with this it does works: if((document.getElementsByTagName("link")[i].getAttribute("rel") == "icon")||(document.getElementsByTagName("link")[i].getAttribute("rel") == "shortcut icon")) . But I need the full URL and not only favicon.png :(

Comment: @xRobot - Do something like: `"http://" + window.location.host + favicon`

Comment: And if you had `icon shortcut`? But yeah, if you add a `||` for each case, that will work :)

Comment: OMG, you're constantly repeating the search?! *Every call* to `getElementsByTagName` has to go search through the DOM. Do it **once** and then loop through the returned `NodeList`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - Thanks for the advise, is this any better? http://jsfiddle.net/PBpgY/2/

Comment: This maybe is better: http://jsfiddle.net/PBpgY/3/

Comment: I know this is an old question, but I wanted to add something that helped me find the absolute path of the favicon, courtesy of this blog post (http://thingsilearned.com/2009/01/19/javascript-relative-and-absolute-urls). I changed `favicon = nodeList[i].getAttribute("href");` to `favicon = nodeList[i].href;`. Ta-daaaaa! :D

Comment: I would recommend adding toLowerCase() for the `if((nodeList[i].getAttribute("rel") == "icon")||(nodeList[i].getAttribute("rel") == "shortcut icon"))` comparison, otherwise it will not find the shortcut icon/icon if SHORTCUT ICON/ICON... my delta: `if((nodeList[i].getAttribute("real").toLowerCase() == "icon")||(nodeList[i].getAttribute("real").toLowerCase() == "shortcut icon"))`.  @NetOperatorWibby, at least in Safari, nodeList[i].href does not guarantee an absolute path for the href.

Comment: @KevinScardina Ooh, that's a great idea, I'll do that.

Comment: just use `document.querySelector("link[rel*='icon']") `

Comment: I agree with @BastienRobert, was gonna comment that as well.

Comment: To convert it to an absolute path, you could use `var link = document.createElement("a"); link.href = getFavicon(); alert(link.protocol + "//" + link.host + link.pathname);`

Answer (score 153):

For people still not getting the favicon with above codes;

1. Most browsers support getting the favicon by sending a request (`/favicon.ico`) themselves, instead of in the html.
2. Another solution is provided by Google.

   To get the favicon for a domain, use:
   `https://s2.googleusercontent.com/s2/favicons?domain=www.stackoverflow.com`

   To get the favicon for an URL, use:
   `https://s2.googleusercontent.com/s2/favicons?domain_url=https://www.stackoverflow.com`

Comment: This should be the correct answer.

Comment: This moved to `https://s2.googleusercontent.com/s2/favicons?domain=http://www.stackoverflow.com`  
 
great solution.

Comment: Note that Google's service re-encodes icons, often visibly reducing quality, sometimes for significant file size reduction but sometimes for little or none.

Comment: How can we detect a missing icon? Google returns a globe icon and a failed Get request.

Comment: ...also Google's services are not available world-wide, so that's a choice.

Comment: any way to determine the size? I see the redirected URL mentions size=16, so may be possible?

Comment: here is the default size=16, Is there any way to overwrite the icon size?

Answer (score 11):

The favicon is at `/favicon.ico` unless you have a `<link rel="icon" href="...">` element. So you can get all of the [`link` elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-link-element.html#the-link-element) via [`document.getElementsByTagName`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-A6C9094) and then look at each of the elements in the returned `NodeList` to see if any of them have the attribute `rel` with the value `"icon"` and, if so, look at its `href`. (You might also look at ones where `rel` is `"shortcut icon"` or `"icon shortcut"` for historical reasons.)

Comment: How can I get the element with rel="shortcut icon" ?

Comment: @xRobot: As I said, you loop through the `NodeList` you got back from `getElementsByTagName`, looking for one with `rel="shortcut icon"` (or just `"icon"`, because that's the newer form). `NodeList` is indexed, so for instance, if you have `var list = document.getElementsByTagName("link");` then `list[0]` is the first matched element, `list[1]` is the second one, etc. There's also a handy `length` property. See the provided links.

Comment: @xRobot `document.querySelector('link[rel="shortcut icon"]')`

Answer (score 7):

Live working fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/sc8qp/2/

Just for good measure and completeness without regex:

```
function getIcons() {
    var links = document.getElementsByTagName('link');
    var icons = [];

    for(var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
        var link = links[i];

        //Technically it could be null / undefined if someone didn't set it!
        //People do weird things when building pages!
        var rel = link.getAttribute('rel');
        if(rel) {
            //I don't know why people don't use indexOf more often
            //It is faster than regex for simple stuff like this
            //Lowercase comparison for safety
            if(rel.toLowerCase().indexOf('icon') > -1) {
                var href = link.getAttribute('href');

                //Make sure href is not null / undefined            
                if(href) {
                    //Relative
                    //Lowercase comparison in case some idiot decides to put the 
                    //https or http in caps
                    //Also check for absolute url with no protocol
                    if(href.toLowerCase().indexOf('https:') == -1 && href.toLowerCase().indexOf('http:') == -1
                        && href.indexOf('//') != 0) {

                        //This is of course assuming the script is executing in the browser
                        //Node.js is a different story! As I would be using cheerio.js for parsing the html instead of document.
                        //Also you would use the response.headers object for Node.js below.

                        var absoluteHref = window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host;

                        if(window.location.port) {
                            absoluteHref += ':' + window.location.port;
                        }

                        //We already have a forward slash
                        //On the front of the href
                        if(href.indexOf('/') == 0) {
                            absoluteHref += href;
                        }
                        //We don't have a forward slash
                        //It is really relative!
                        else {
                            var path = window.location.pathname.split('/');
                            path.pop();
                            var finalPath = path.join('/');

                            absoluteHref += finalPath + '/' + href;
                        }

                        icons.push(absoluteHref);
                    }
                    //Absolute url with no protocol
                    else if(href.indexOf('//') == 0) {
                        var absoluteUrl = window.location.protocol + href;

                        icons.push(absoluteUrl);
                    }
                    //Absolute
                    else {
                        icons.push(href);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return icons;
}
```