# get favicon.co from WKWebView

Tags: objective-c, swift, webview, favicon, wkwebview

I am using the new wkWebView for OS X and iOS. For a presentation of the webview as an icon, I need the favicon of the presented URL. In the old webview, I could use the function:

```
var mainFrameIcon: NSImage! { get }
```

How can I get the image by using wkWebView in Swift or Objective-C?

Answer (score 2):

Like many others have said in this thread, finding a favicon isn't a straightforward thing anymore.

As such, I've developed an open source framework that does the heavy lifting for you.
https://github.com/will-lumley/FaviconFinder/

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the new WKWebView class doesn't feature any public built in favicon but there is an easy way you can retrieve this. Since websites store the favicon url at /favicon.ico so you can simply just get the host url from the web view, add /favicon.ico to the end and get the url as an nsimage

Do it like this:

```
NSURL *webpageURL = myWebView.URL;
NSString *hostURL = webpageURL.host;
NSString *faviconURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://%@/favicon.ico",hostURL];
NSImage *faviconImage = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:faviconURL]];
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I'm a little nervous with this approach. Many sites now specify the icon in their HTML. Also, this approach doesn't use https.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, getting the favicon is no longer a single straightforward property. The reason is that websites can declare multiple favicons for different resolutions. You (the application developer) need to choose the appropriate icon for your needs.

Another complication is that you (the application developer) need to execute Javascript in the WKWebView object to get the favicons from link tags!

(Note: relying on /favicon.ico is error-prone. Some websites don't update their CMS's /favicon.ico and only set it via the link tags. In this case, a page that has the correct icon in Chrome might show a Drupal icon in your custom browser.)

Here is both the Javascript to parse the link tags, and then the Swift to further read the result.

```
// Based on code from  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10282939/how-to-get-favicons-url-from-a-generic-webpage-in-javascript
static private var GET_FAVICON_SCRIPT = """
    var favicons = [];
    var nodeList = document.getElementsByTagName('link');
    for (var i = 0; i < nodeList.length; i++)
    {
        if((nodeList[i].getAttribute('rel') == 'icon')||(nodeList[i].getAttribute('rel') == 'shortcut icon'))
        {
            const node = nodeList[i];
            favicons.push({
                url: node.getAttribute('href'),
                sizes: node.getAttribute('sizes')
            });
        }
    }
    favicons;
"""

public private(set) var faviconUrls = Set<FaviconUrl>()

func updateFavicon() {
    self.webView.evaluateJavaScript(TabViewController.GET_FAVICON_SCRIPT) { (result, error) in
        // Favicon is returned from Javascript as an NSMutableArray with NSMutableDictionaries
        // Needs to be turned into a list
        var faviconUrls = Set<FaviconUrl>();

        // If the script returned correctly
        if let favicons = result as? NSArray {
            for faviconObject in favicons {
                if let faviconDictionary = faviconObject as? NSDictionary {
                    if let urlString = faviconDictionary["url"] as? String {
                        
                        // The favicon url (href in link tag) needs to be resolved to the url from the page
                        if let url = URL(string: urlString, relativeTo: self.webView.url) {
                            let sizesString = faviconDictionary["sizes"] as? String;
                            let sizeStrings = sizesString?.components(separatedBy: "x") ?? []
                            
                            if (sizeStrings.count == 2) {
                                let width = Int(sizeStrings[0])
                                let height = Int(sizeStrings[1])
                                faviconUrls.insert(FaviconUrl(url: url, width: width, height: height))
                            } else {
                                faviconUrls.insert(FaviconUrl(url: url, width: nil, height: nil))
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        
        // If no favicons were found, fallback to /favicon.ico
        // Note that some sites never replace the one that comes with the CMS. If you don't
        // use Javascript to parse the <link ...> tags, a site that works correctly in Chrome
        // could have a Drupal icon in your application
        if faviconUrls.count == 0 {
            if let webViewUrl = self.webView.url {
                let schemeAndHostUrl = webViewUrl.deletingPathExtension()
                let url = schemeAndHostUrl.appendingPathComponent("favicon.ico")
                faviconUrls.insert(FaviconUrl(url: url, width: nil, height: nil))
            }
        }
        
        if (faviconUrls != self.faviconUrls) {
            self.faviconUrls = faviconUrls
            self.delegate?.faviconChanged()
        }
        
        if error != nil {
            NSLog("Can not determine favicons: %@", error?.localizedDescription ?? "")
        }
    }
}
```

For completeness, here the FaviconUrl class:

```
import Cocoa

class FaviconUrl: NSObject {

    public private(set) var url: URL
    public private(set) var width: Int?
    public private(set) var height: Int?
    
    init(url: URL, width: Int?, height: Int?) {
        self.url = url
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
    }
    
    public var area: Int? {
        get {
            if let width = self.width {
                if let height = self.height {
                    return width * height;
                }
            }
            
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```