# How to add the websites logo in html?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Basically, this is a part of a bookmark app that I am making with html,css,javascript. In the below code I wanted to get the websites logo along with the bookmark how could I do this in the code.

```
for(var i=0;i<bookmarks.length;i++)
{
var name=bookmarks[i].name;
var url=bookmarks[i].url;
bookmarksresults.innerHTML+='<div class="well">'+ 
                            '<h3>'+name+ 
                            '<a class="btn btn-default" target="_blank" 
                             href="'+url+'">Visit</a> '+
                            '<a onclick="deleteBookmark(\''+url+'\')" +
                            class="btn btn-danger" href="#">Delete</a> '+
                            '</h3>' +
                            '</div>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just add in

```
<img src=" +logo.png+ " />
```

After the h3 tag, and just make sure to replace the logo.png with the correct naem for the image.

But, the question was a little vague, let me know if this is what you wanted.

Comment: My question was when I bookmark a website in this app how could I get the website brand logo along with the bookmark I did.Basically, I was talking about the favicons.

Comment: Oh, with that in mind I would suggest a search for the sites, favi.ico image and saving that image. However, as a way to do that I am of little help, I apologize

Answer (score 0):

Use the `<img>` tag

```
bookmarksresults.innerHTML+='<div class="well">'+ 
                            '<h3>'+name+ 
                            '<a class="btn btn-default" target="_blank" 
                             href="'+url+'">Visit&nbsp;<img src="logo.png" alt="Logo" height="42" width="42"></a> '+
                            '<a onclick="deleteBookmark(\''+url+'\')" +
                            class="btn btn-danger" href="#">Delete</a> '+
                            '</h3>' +
                            '</div>';
```

If you want to put the favicon: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/10283308/1914034

```
var getFavicon = function(){
    var favicon = undefined;
    var nodeList = document.getElementsByTagName("link");
    for (var i = 0; i < nodeList.length; i++)
    {
        if((nodeList[i].getAttribute("rel") == "icon")||(nodeList[i].getAttribute("rel") == "shortcut icon"))
        {
            favicon = nodeList[i].getAttribute("href");
        }
    }
    return favicon;        
}

bookmarksresults.innerHTML+='<div class="well">'+ 
                                '<h3>'+name+ 
                                '<a class="btn btn-default" target="_blank" 
                                 href="'+url+'">Visit&nbsp;<img src="'+ getFavicon() +'" alt="Logo" height="42" width="42"></a> '+
                                '<a onclick="deleteBookmark(\''+url+'\')" +
                                class="btn btn-danger" href="#">Delete</a> '+
                                '</h3>' +
                                '</div>';
```