# Get top sites favicon - browser extension

Tags: javascript, browser-extension

I'm using the `topSites` API to get a list of the user most visited websites.

```
browser.topSites.get().then( (mostVisitedURL) => {
  console.log(mostVisitedURL);
});
```

Is possible to get also the favicons for each website? I see that in forefox there is the ability to set options but this isn't available in chrome.

Comment: What does the documentation say?

Comment: As you can read from the question, the api is implemented in a different way in firefox. I need a solution to get the favicons also in chrome!

Comment: Consider reading the chrome documentation? Or are you asking us to do that for you? --- If it's not available, then it's likely not possible.

Comment: If the browser doesn't provide such information, then you must write something to achieve it. Take a look [at this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10282939/how-to-get-favicons-url-from-a-generic-webpage-in-javascript) for a solution to retrieve favicons.